# Maximize an MDIChild of another application VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, winapi, mdichild

I'm making an appication that needs to maximize the window of another application. In Spy++, the way it works is -> "Working Model - Untitled1" -> "MDICloient" -> "Untitled1"

This is what the tree view looks like.

I need to maximize Untitled1, but I'm not sure how. I tried findwindow "Working Model - Untitled1" and then used get and setwindowplacment for it, and it worked. Then I used findwindowex on "Untitled1" but it did not maximize. What am I doing wrong here? I'm sure mdi windows can be maximized; the "Untitled1" window itself has the 3 buttons (- + X) on the caption bar.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by finding the handle of the mdiclient, then the afxframe... then I used get and set window position.